# Starting / Shutting down Problem

Tags: startup, shutdown, reboot, restart

I have 12.04 installed on my laptop. There is the following starting/shutting down problem:

When clicking the power button, the laptop starts for 1 second and after that abruptly shuts down. When starting again everything works normal. But after shutting down and starting again, the PC again has the same problem.

This problem wasn't there when using Windows. What can I do?

Comment: Are you pressing the power button on your laptop or actually going to the system menu and clicking shut down?

Comment: For shutting down I go to the system menu and click shut down.

Comment: Please include more detail. Right now this question is lacking detail so it may be closed as Not a Real Question as it cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: Here are further details:

Comment: Here are further details: the laptop is a Medion MD 96350, Intel Core 2 Duo Prozessor T5250, 2 GB RAM, Intel GMA X3100 graphic card. Ubuntu was installed via USB. Setting the BIOS to default didnt solve the problem, the BIOS itself also seems okay, because the time works and the problem just appeared, after installing Ubuntu. The problem is the following: When starting the Laptop it abruptly shuts down after it 1 second (maybe 1,5 seconds), before showing anything to the screen. When pushing the power button again, the PC starts normally. After shutting down the problem is again the same.

Answer (score 0):

A 1sec startup won't reach the operation system startup at all.
I'd suggest resetting your BIOS to default values and/or checking the BIOS battery if there is one in a laptop (which I'm not sure of)

Comment: I resetted the BIOS, but the problem is still there. The BIOS Battery should be also okay, because the problem just came up, after I installed Ubuntu, before there never was that problem. Also the clock etc. works fine.